# Selecting picture from phone's memory and setting it as background

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have repeated the methodology described by the answers founds in this website, but my app is not working properly.

When I press the button to select the image new window opens that shows all the folders containing the pictures. When I select one image by just tapping on it, the window for selecting the pictures disappears without asking for any confirmation and no image is set as background in my app.

I'm testing it on the Nexus 5x with Android Marshmallow. I would appreciate any help.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

ImageView bgImage;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeButton);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        bgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgImage);
        bgImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
}
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.marat.tutorialimageupload.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/changeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Image"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

`if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)`

The `requestCode` cannot simultaneously be `RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE` *and* `RESULT_OK`. Change this to the following:

`if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && null != data)`

It's the `resultCode` that is passed into `onActivityResult` that you need to check for `RESULT_OK`, not the `requestCode`. Hope this resolves the problem you have.

**EDIT**

Okay. Maybe these modifications to your code can help:

1. First move this line `bgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgImage);` to your `onCreate`.
2. Next, set the intent type before calling `startActivityForResult` like this: `intent.setType("image/*");`
3. Then change the code inside the `if` condition in `onActivityResult` to this:

   ```
           Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
           CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
           Bitmap bm;
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
           bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options); 
           bgImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
   ```

Comment: Thats funny) Thank you for finding the bug. I have corrected the code. But  the behavior of app did not change. It is still is not setting the imageview with selected picture :(

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. BTW, I have replaced the "projection" with "filePathColumn" and "selectedImagePath" with "picturePath". I wish I had other smartphone with older version of android where I could test it. Maybe it would work

Comment: Could you print some Log messages and check for the parameters passed into the `onActivityResult`? Oh, and are you asking for runtime permissions or declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the manifest?

Comment: Now I have got it fixed :) You were right I forgot to add the permissions to the manifest but it solved the problem on older version of android than 6.0. On Marshmallow I went to the settgins and gave the permission to use memory to the app. Then it worked. Now I need to make app ask for permissions. Once again, thank you)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)